# How to set the settings to open help of evc 4.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, evc4, evc

I am new in evc. I have a problem, whenever I select any keyword and press F1, the help is opened and shows the index page, in which the particular keyword is showed but the details regarding to the keyword is not shown. I have to search that keyword. Can anybody tell me what happening is this or any setting regarding to the evc help is changed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure SDK is installed properly

With F1 you should be able to search your help contents if the index page is opened as you had mentioned.